# What is the right network settings in order to ping the IP address of the printer successfully?

Tags: networking, printing, hp, ip, ping

I have installed `hplip-3.17.10.run` and `hplip-3.17.10-plugin.run` on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. After that, I invoked `hp-setup` in terminal or clicked `HP Device Manager` to find and add the printer.
I chose the second line `Network/Ethernet/Wireless network (direct connection or JetDirect)` in the panel, and the option `Avahi` in `Network discovery method` must be chosen at the same time, which is shown in [options in hp-setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTBXl.png).

Under these options, the printer in my office can be found and added ([to add the printer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dh4kM.png)). However, the problem still exists. The printer gives nothing when I try to print a test page. And the error `Device communication error (code 5012)` popped up in `HP Device Manager`. After several attempts after these days, I think the problem is caused by that I can not ping the IP address of the printer on my Ubuntu.

The IP address of my computer is a fixed address, which is 210.XX.77.XXX in this case. And the Subnet mask, gateway and DNS are also given by the administrator of the network of our company. The IP address of the printer is 169.254.162.214. All the computers and the printer are connected to the switch in our office.

In Windows, a method which is shown in the following link [setting in Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/px3Ew.jpg) is used. It seems this is the common way used in Windows OS.

However, I do not know what should I do when I changed to Ubuntu. I tried to use a similar method which is shown in the following link ([my setting in Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsDzY.png)). However, it seems it doesn't work.

Could you please tell me how should I change the setting of my network in Ubuntu in order to ping the IP address of the printer successfully? 
One more thing is that I can not change the IP address of the printer at this time because the other ones in my office are using Windows and connected the printer with the IP address 169.254.162.214.

Any help would be much appreciated!

PS: One strange thing is, the day before yesterday, I can ping the printer successfully and the printer can print the test page when I turn on the computer. I thought I had fixed the problem. However, after restarted my Ubuntu, I still can not ping the printer on my Ubuntu.

Comment: Ask your network administrator about adding your printer to the network.  The printer is not receiving a DHCP address or not assigned an IP address so it is not on the same subnet.  169.254.x.x IP addresses happen when a device is not statically assigned and it not seeing a DHCP server.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much! Because this is just an issue in our own office, there is nobody in charge of this local network. I thought although IP address of 169.254.x.x is used by the printer, maybe there is a solution existed which might be similar to that in Windows. The sad thing is that I cannot change the IP address of the printer since everybody else is using it well on Windows. Looking forward very much to your further help!

Comment: The only other thing you could do is to remove the static IP from your Ubuntu so that it goes to the 169.254.x.x IP addressing.

Comment: Do you mean I should choose DHCP in the setting of IPv4? If I remove the static IP in my Ubuntu, the network of my Ubuntu would be disconneted.

Comment: Write down all the IP address information on your Ubuntu so that you can put it all in.  I think though that it might be easier if A) you had a second network card in your Ubuntu that could be attached to the Windows network side.  Or B) had the Windows network setup to match that of the Ubuntu.  Subnetting networks can be complicated.

Comment: I am really sorry that I do not quite understand your reply. I think I have copied the corresponding sections into Ubuntu, please see the links in my original post. However, it seems this is not working. I installed Windows and Ubuntu on my computer, but I cannot use both of them at the same time. And I think my computer only has one network card. Looking forward to more comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The IP addresses in the 169.254.0.0/16 block are used for link-local addressing (network configuration) and are therefor not routable. It's a wonder this ever worked. Either your printer is configured to this address manually and your router is correctly dropping it or the printer isn't able to automatically configure itself with an IP address from the router so it defaults to a link-local address.

More than likely its the latter. DHCP needs to be activated on the printer. (Or less likely your router doesn't have DHCP enabled or its bugged) You'll need to connect your printer directly to a computer (link-local) and configure it via the web interface.

Comment: The JetDirect application may also have a way of changing the IP address or enabling DHCP a lot of older printers do that. But the same concept applies. You can't route a link-local address so configuration will have to be done with the printer directly connected.

Comment: Thanks very much! All the computers and the printer are connected to the switch in our office. I do not fully know the difference but maybe the situation is slightly different from connecting to a router? Although the IP address of the printer is 169.254.x.x, the solution in Windows is rather simple. So I hoped I can find a similar solution in Ubuntu before I posted this question for help in Ask Ubuntu.